# substring: row information to field names

Tags: sqlite, subquery

I have information in an SQLite database. The database structure can not be changed.

[image: Illustration]

I am trying to construct a query that will give me a result in which the TypeOfInformation entries are field names:

[image: Illustration]

My first try was to work with subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT Value FROM FinData WHERE Type = 'Price') AS Price,
       (SELECT Value FROM FinData WHERE Type = 'Volume') AS Volume
FROM FinData")
```

Seemed perfect, however, the result was a resultset in which EVERY entry in the columns `Price` and `Volume` are equal to the FIRST respective entry of `Price` and `Volume` in the original database:

[image: Illustration]

I tried to get around this and to include the other Price  and Volume information ­- but I failed. (Which is a pity, because the syntax seemed somehow easy to grasp.)

Next try was the following:

```
Select Date, Value AS Volume From FinData WHERE Volume IN 
(SELECT Value FROM FinData WHERE (Type = 'Volume'))
```

This gives me a resultset with a Volume column and all volume information. Okay, so far. However, when I want to complement this resultset which a Price column via

```
Select Date, Value AS Volume From FinData WHERE Volume IN 
(SELECT Value FROM FinData WHERE (Type = 'Volume'))
union
Select Date, Value AS Close From FinData WHERE Price IN 
(SELECT Value FROM FinData WHERE (Type = 'Price'))
```

I get a resultset that shows Price and Volume information in only ONE column ("Volume"), which therefore is also useless.

Answer (score 1):

To look up a value corresponding to a row in the outer query, you have to use a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub), which explicitly makes a connection between both:

```
SELECT Date,
       (SELECT Value
        FROM FinData
        WHERE Date = Dates.Date
          AND TypeOfInformation = 'Price'
       ) AS Price,
       (SELECT Value
        FROM FinData
        WHERE Date = Dates.Date
          AND TypeOfInformation = 'Volume'
       ) AS Volume
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date
      FROM FinData) AS Dates;
```

(The DISTINCT subquery is used to prevent multiple rows for each date.)

Alternatively, group all rows for a date, and use aggregation functions and [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to extract the values from the proper rows:

```
SELECT Date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfInformation = 'Price'  THEN Value END) AS Price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TypeOfInformation = 'Volume' THEN Value END) AS Volume
FROM FinData
GROUP BY Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dates are unique per price volume pair, you can do this:

```
with xxx(date,price,volume) as
  (
   select date,value,0 from findata where typeofinformation = 'Price'
   union
   select date,0,value from findata where typeofinformation = 'Volume'
  )
  select date,sum(price) price,sum(volume) volume from xxx group by date;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, however, having pasted your code in my SQLite Browser, it gives me an error.

Comment: @WiWi Thank you very much for keeping the error message secret.